# Plotting R function

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot the number of students (Say 365) against the respective probability at least 2 are born on the same day.

I cannot seem to get it to plot the graph. Code runs but not sure.

```
nstudents <- function(x){

result = (1 - (factorial(365)/ 365^x*factorial(365-x)))
return(result)
}

x <- 2:365
y <- nstudents(x)

plot(x, y,
 main = "Number of Students VS Probability of atleast two born on same day",
 xlab = "x",
 ylab = "y",
 xlim = c(2, 365),
 ylim = c(0, 1),
 #type = "l",
 lwd = 5,
 col = "darkred")
```

This is the first bit of R code I have ever run so please do excuse my incompetence. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit- After trying to print the output it appears it may be something to do with my formula. However I am not sure how to better formulate that as that is the exact formula.

Additional formula I am trying to use:

```
nstudents <- function(x){

result = (1 - exp(1)^((-x(x-1))/730))
print(result)
return(result)
}
```

However the above results in the following error:

```
Error in x(x - 1): could not find function "x"
```

Is this because it is assuming x(x-1) is a function? Would I need to create a separate function for this?

Comment: First you should test the function. Note that `nstudents(1)` returns negative infinity. None of your `y` values seem to be finite. The problem is those values for factorial are enormous and are well outside the range of what R or most programming languages can represent. Also be careful with order of operations and make sure you group all your denominator values together. When factorials get to big it's often a good idea to switch to the log of the factorial and there is a `lfactorial` function for that.

Comment: @MrFlick Okay, will do so. Have not used this before. nstudents(1) is not meant to be allowed. It should start at 2 as there needs to be more than 1 students in order for there to be a probability at least 2 share a b-day. Could you take a look at my updated formula and possibly let me know how I can get this one to work instead? It does not use factorials.

Comment: `-x(x-1)` is not valid syntax in R. It should be `-x * (x-1)`. There is no implicit multiplication with parenthesis.

Comment: @MrFlick Perfect, it works now. Thanks for your help. Will get used to the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your function, which has a couple of issues. First of all, you have written:

```r
result = (1 - (factorial(365)/ 365^x*factorial(365-x)))
```

Your demoninator should be `365^x * factorial(365-x)`, but the way you have written this means it is interpreted as `(factorial(365) / 365^x) * factorial(365-x)` because you have not explicitly wrapped the denominator in parentheses.

However, this doesn't really help, since `factorial(365)` is simply too large a number to represent in 64-bit floating point computers. You need to carry out the calculation in log format using `lfactorial` as MrFlick suggests, so your function would become:

```r
nstudents <- function(n) {
  1 - exp(lfactorial(365) - n * log(365) - lfactorial(365 - n))
}
```

This allows:

```r
x <- 2:365
y <- nstudents(x)

plot(x, y,
     main = paste("Number of Students VS Probability of at",
                  "least two born on same day"),
     xlab = "x",
     ylab = "y",
     xlim = c(0, 365),
     ylim = c(0, 1),
     col = "darkred")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was not sure how to implement the log function so that helps. Managed to figure out a different notation and I see what you meant by my notation so thanks for pointing that out for me. Ended up with the same thing.